# Is there a way to start a Linux machine automatically?

Tags: linux, power-management

On Mac machines the user can schedule the machine to power-on automatically, is there anything for Linux that gives us the same ability? I can schedule shut downs whenever I want, it's powering up that I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your hardware supports it, you should be able to set the alarm from within linux by writing to `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` or `/proc/acpi/alarm`.  More info [here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup#Using_.2Fsys.2Fclass.2Frtc.2Frtc0.2Fwakealarm) and [here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup#Archive:_Using_.2Fproc.2Facpi.2Falarm), respectively.  Note that this facility may become available with a BIOS update.

It may also be possible for this option to be available even if the BIOS interface doesn't allow it to be set.  My laptop has a bare-bones BIOS interface, but although I haven't tried to wake it via the alarm, it looks like it's possible.  This is based on the fact that one of the `/var/log/kern.log*` files contains the text `RTC can wake from S4`, and from the presence of the (empty) pseudo-file `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`.  More on that at [the same page](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup#BIOS_setup) linked to by the above links.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about OS, it's about the hardware.

Some BIOSes have a "wake on RTC alarm" option.
Assuming that your bootloader doesn't want for user input forever, your OS shall boot as soon as BIOS powers on the computer at certain time.

Comment: I thought it might be so. It's a pity I can't access that from the OS, makes it a bit tedious setting it if I have to restart first.